# to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

i have 1 error when i try to use html in jquery to add product quantity to cart but cant add even though click event is caught.when the click event is done, get the value in the APIController with Id "cart-number", it cannot be called.when i work with ajax the console shows the error:failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
anyone help?
this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cart-btn").click(function(){
        var color_id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").attr("data-color");
        var color_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find(".quantity").text();
        
        var product_name = $("#detail-title").text();
        var product_id = $("#detail-title").attr("data-Id");
        var price = $("#detail-price").attr("data-value");
        
           $.ajax({
            url:"/PhoneAccessories/api/addtocart",
            type:"GET",
            data:{
                product_id:product_id,
                color_id:color_id,
                quantity:quantity,
                product_name:product_name,
                price:price,
                color_name:color_name
            },
            success: function(value){
                $("#cart-number").html("<span>"+value+"</span>");
            }
        })
    
    });
});
```

this is my APIController

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping("api/")
    @SessionAttributes({"email","cart"})
    public class APIController {
        @Autowired
        EmployeeService employeeService;
        
        @GetMapping("addtocart")
        public String AddToCart(@RequestParam int product_id,@RequestParam int color_id,@RequestParam int quantity,@RequestParam String product_name,@RequestParam String price,@RequestParam String color_name,HttpSession httpSession) {
            
            if(httpSession.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
                List<ProductCart> productCarts = new ArrayList<ProductCart>();
                ProductCart carts = new ProductCart();
                carts.setProduct_id(product_id);
                carts.setColor_id(color_id);
                carts.setQuantity(1);
                carts.setProduct_name(product_name);
                carts.setPrice(price);
                carts.setColor_name(color_name);
                productCarts.add(carts);
                httpSession.setAttribute("cart", productCarts);
                List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
                return listCart.size()+ "";
            }else {
                List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
                int location = CheckProductAlreadyExists(product_id, color_id, httpSession);
                if(location == -1) {
                    
                    ProductCart carts = new ProductCart();
                    carts.setProduct_id(product_id);
                    carts.setColor_id(color_id);
                    carts.setQuantity(1);
                    carts.setProduct_name(product_name);
                    carts.setPrice(price);
                    carts.setColor_name(color_name);
                    listCart.add(carts);
                }else {
                    
                    int newQuantity = listCart.get(location).getQuantity()+1;
                    listCart.get(location).setQuantity(newQuantity);
                }
                return listCart.size() +"";
                
            }
            
            
        }
        private int CheckProductAlreadyExists(int product_id,int color_id,HttpSession httpSession) {
            List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
            for(int i=0;i<listCart.size();i++) {
                if(listCart.get(i).getProduct_id()== product_id && listCart.get(i).getColor_id() ==color_id ) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

this is the jsp details page:

```
<body>
    <section id="detail-page">

        <nav>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"><div id="cart-number"><span>${NumberOfProduct}</span></div></i> 
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${fc != null}">
                        <a id="first-char" href="login/"> ${fc} </i></a>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <a href="/PhoneAccessories/login/"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

            </div>

        </nav>


    </section>
    
    <!-- Detail Product -->
    
    <div id="container-detail" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="product-category" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                        <img id="image-detail" src='<c:url value="/resources/Image/products/${product.getProduct_image()}"/>' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                        <h4 id="detail-title" data-Id="${product.getProduct_id()}" >${product.getProduct_name()}</h4>
                        <h5 id="detail-price" data-value="${product.getProduct_price()}" >${product.getProduct_price()}</h5>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Color</td>
                                    <td>Quantity</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <c:forEach var="detailProduct" items="${product.getProduct_Details()}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="color" data-color="${detailProduct.getProduct_Color().getColor_id()}" >${detailProduct.getProduct_Color().getColor_name()}</td>
                                        <td class="quantity" data-quantity="${detailProduct.getQuantity()}" >${detailProduct.getQuantity()}</td>
                                        <td><button id="product-button" class="cart-btn">shop now</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <h5>Description</h5>
                <span>${product.getDescription_product()}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
</body>
```

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized. Do you use athentication?